# Skip particular step in forloop Django

Tags: django, for-loop, skip

HI i am using a forloop in django template

```
{% for image in images %}
{% endfor %}
```

> which executes for 10 steps

but i want to skip the 5th step and execute for remaining
how can i do this please suggest ...

Answer (score 5):

```
{% for image in images %}
   {% if forloop.counter != 5 %}
    ...
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /shop/product/Cora-2/

Could not parse the remainder: '!=5' from '!=5'  it throws this error after using above

Comment: What version of django do you use?

Comment: If you use 1.1 or earlier (oh my), use `{% ifnotequal forloop.counter 5 %} ... {% endifnotequal %}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for image in images %}
   {% if forloop.counter0 != 5 %}
    ...
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this works for me